# Is it standard for Del Rey digital books to not include cover images?

Tags: books, publishing

I've purchased two titles (epub format), and there are no cover images. Otherwise they are everything to be expected. In place of the cover image is some placeholder image which is the Ballantine/Del Rey logo in green.

Legally, I can't purchase the Orion/Gallancz versions, since those are only for sale in the UK (though I'm told that these include cover art).

What's the deal here? Are they too cheap to get the digital distribution rights from the artists? They're not printing the books with plain green covers. Hell, I would even think that book covers are work-for-hire, and wouldn't require additional royalties for ebooks (might be wrong on that though).

I'm tempted to attempt downloading them elsewhere, but in truth I mostly want an explanation.

[Del Rey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_Rey_Books) is a publisher that deals almost exclusively with science fiction and fantasy works.

Comment: Where did you purchase these books?

Comment: If you put them into [Calibre Library Manager](https://calibre-ebook.com/), you can add whatever cover you want to your epubs

Comment: Do you know if the covers are included if you buy another (non-epub) format?  It maybe a digital rights issue if they don't have permission to redistribute the art in a way that it might be separated from the book.

Comment: @DavidW When I purchased these, I was not given an option of anything but epub. I think azw is a Amazon/Kindle-only thing, and they must keep a monopoly on those. The website I purchased from does seem to have licensed things properly. Looking at some other titles it appears that pdf is an option for some, but not all, on that site.

Comment: @Valorum I am aware of its ability to do that, but it's not clear which cover I'd even use. Having trouble figuring out which is which for these. And if I have to do this for other titles in the future, they ought to be paying me to do the book editing. It's irritating.

Comment: Goodreads offers a range of covers for each edition

Comment: Infuriating right ??

Comment: @Fattie I'd probably say "irritating", but yeh. I'd like to understand this, so I can avoid either the publishers or the titles that aren't fully typeset. If I wanted bad epub files, I'd download from the one place that shall not be named.

Comment: :/  so true, @JohnO